# Как в Notepad++ поставить несколько курсоров?

Tags: notepad++, курсор

Как поставить несколько курсоров в notepad++ , в sumblime это делается зажатым ctrl + левая кнопка мыши. а в notepad++ как ?

Answer (score 9):

Все есть, нужно просто включить эту возможность.
На [сайте notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/multi-editing.html) все очень хорошо рассказано.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очень интересно:)

Comment: С Вашего позволения (от меня плюсик, а не минусик :)

Comment: Спасибо чувак :)